# I'm trying to run an app from GitHub running on Android Studio that has No Module on it to run the app. Some apps from GitHub have a Module

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to run an app from GitHub running on Android Studio that has No Module on it to run the app. Some apps from GitHub have a Module. Some apps from GitHub don't have a Module. How do I get the correct Module for the app to run https://github.com/mthli/Ninja
I got the code here.
https://github.com/mthli/Ninja.git
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Lgt.png)

Comment: That is a very old project that had been developed for Eclipse not Android Studio. The build.xml marks it as Maven project not Gradle as it is used by AS. Even if you would manage to build this project the code would require a lot of adaptions to make it run on recent Android versions.